# Is there a way for a java applet to determine at run time where it was downloaded from?

Tags: java, applet

Maintaining an signed applet that opens connections to the server it was downloaded from. Currently it determines the server location from a properties file that is located in the downloaded signed jar file.

This requires a separate build for qa vs production since the properties file needs to be edited before creating the signed jar. Any way to do the determination of the location of the server at run time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems you're looking for [`Applet.getCodeBase()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getCodeBase%28%29).

Comment: Thanks, looks like this should work. I'm the one that was missing this.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this, if the page the applet is embedded in is dynamic, is to pass the current server's URL in as a parameter to the applet.